# Java SE 6 compiled application deployed to Java SE 7 runtime environment - random JVM crashes, no Throwables?

Tags: java, jvm, java-7, java-6

As in subject, I have a Java SE application compiled using Java 1.6 deployed on a Java 1.7 runtime environment. As Java is highly backwards compatible, I assumed all would be well - but ever since it has been deployed in the 1.7 environment, users are experiencing random JVM crashes - i.e. the whole JVM exits randomly.

There's nothing in any error logs (catching all throwables) - which suggests this is happening outside of my application.

Is this behavior expected?

Comment: `Is this behavior expected?` Well, did you expect it?

Comment: Anything in [Incompatibilities between Java SE 7 and Java SE 6](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-417013.html#incompatibilities) that might help you to pinpoint the issue?

Comment: @DavidPostill - went through this before deploying to the 1.7 environment; nothing untoward there unfortunately

Comment: What is the process exit code?

Answer (score 2):

Using Java 6 (or earlier) libraries with a Java 7 JVM should work.

Have you checked for fatal error logs?
When the JVM crashes, an error log is written with the default name `java_error`*pid*`.log`.
You can specify the name with the flag `-XX:ErrorFile={Path}/{Name of Log file}`

```
java -XX:ErrorFile=myerrorlogfile.log ...
```

Answer (score 2):

I think, first focus should be on getting the exception.
Some of the causes, why exception is not logged, could be:

- The application code has a call to “System.exit”
- Application crashed while executing some low level assembly code
- application crashed during VM startup or shutdown

To handle this, execute the application with

```
-Xdump:java:system:events=vmstop+user
-Xtrace:trigger=method{java/lang/System.exit,javadump} 
-Xcheck:jni:verbose
```

Also it could be useful, to check if your compile time and runtime is of same JDK implementation - like Oracle JDK or OpenJDK. Technically there shouldn't be an issue. But in practice, I have faced issues.

Also try increasing the heap size, with

```
-Xms512m -Xmx1152m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:MaxNewSize=256m
```